# Javascript: Can a string be cast as/converted to a type constant?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

If I have a variable containing a string, is there a way that I can treat the contents of that string as the name of a type?

For example, is there a `????` in Javascript such that:

```
var ts = "Array";
var magic_type = ????; //magic
var obj_instance = new magic_type;
```

is valid and `obj_instance == []` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate it by using bracket notation with the global object.

```
var arr = new window['Array'];
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VWBg/).

If the constructor takes arguments, add them to the end.

As a side note, your code example...

```
obj_instance === []
```

...won't ever evaluate to `true` because the `[]` syntax will create a new `Array` with a different memory location.

Comment: With an Addendum:

you can chain this idea, too:

`window['google']['visualization']['PieChart']`

Answer (score 1):

```
var instance = new window[someString]();
```

No magic required.